# Alternating rest arguments

Tags: javascript, syntax, parameters, arguments

Is there a syntatically concise way to create indefinite amount of arguments that alternate? The following is an example of what I want to achive:

```
myFunction('foo',1);
///performs action A with 'foo', then action B with 1;

myFunction('foo', 1, 'bar', 2, 'FOO', 3, 'BAR', 4);
///performs action A with 'foo', then action B with 1;
///performs action A with 'bar', then action B with 2;
///performs action A with 'FOO', then action B with 3;
///performs action A with 'BAR', then action B with 4;
```

I know you might use rest parameters with this one...but is there any way (or with any other operators) to achieve the kind of function above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator to do one thing with the even indexed elements and another thing with the odd indexed elements like so:

```js
const doA = (arg) => console.log(`A: ${arg}`);
const doB = (arg) => console.log(`B: ${arg}`);

function myFunction(...args) {
  args.forEach((el, i) => {
    i % 2 === 0 ? doA(el) : doB(el);
  });
}

myFunction("foo", 1, "bar", 2, "baz", 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this quite easily - assuming I've interpreted correctly that by "performs action A with 'foo'" you mean "call function A with foo as the argument":

```
function myFunction(...args) {
    args.forEach((arg, i) => {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            A(arg);
        }
        else {
            B(arg);
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow-up to the other answers:

If you cannot use the ES6 spread operator `...` (which is to be preferred),  you can use the  `arguments` array as a replacement for `...args`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments